# geolocation HTML5 on firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am trying out geolocation with HTML5. For some reason it works on firefox inconsistently and it does not work on chrome and throws an error called object positionerror.

2 questions

1.) How do i see the actual error (sorry I am new to javascript)
2.) Why is it working differently on chrome and firefox?

The script is as below -

```
<script>

if(!navigator.geolocation) {
    alert ('your browser sux');
} else {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}

function success(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

    document.write(lat + ', ' + lng);

} 


function error(error) {
    alert ('damn error' +error);




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have to be hard to debug. Every reasonably modern browser has a debugger:

- Safari, Chrome, IE8+ and Firefox 4 have built-in developer tools
- For Firefox 3 and 4, there's also [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)

As for the actual issues with using `navigator.geolocation`, you might be interested in the [Dive Into HTML5 Geolocation chapter](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/geolocation.html).

---

To get to Chrome's Developer Tools, either:

- `Wrench -> Tools -> Developer Tools`, or
- `View -> Developer -> Developer Tools`

If you want to see the JavaScript code, add breakpoints, step through the code, etc. you'd use the `Scripts` tab. The other tab I spend most of my time in is the `Console`.